# convert from string to int by atoi?

Tags: c++, string

Here I have a function to convert a string to int and store into an array 
but it does not work and i get this expiration  :

```
'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str' to create a pointer to member
```

how can i fix it ??
help me please 
note :number[] is int 
eq is string

```
void calcu(string s)
    {
        int size = s.size();
        string d = "", st="";
        int y = 1;
        int g = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == '-')
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    y = -1;
                else
                if (isdigit(s[i - 1]))
                    y = 1;
                else
                if (s[i - 1] == '(')
                    y = -1;
                else
                if (ispunct(s[i - 1]))
                    y = -1;
                else
                    st += s[i];## Heading ##
            }
            else
            if (isdigit(s[i]))
                d += s[i];
            else
            {
                if (d != "")
                {
                    number[g] = atoi(d.c_str);
                    number[g] *= y;
                    y = 1;
                    arr[g] = char(65 + g);
                    st += arr[g];
                    st += s[i];
                    g++;
                    d = "";
                }
                st += s[i];
            }
        }
        eq = st;
    }
```

Comment: `d.c_str` should be `d.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

`c_str` is a method, so it should be called with brackets:

```
number[g] = atoi(d.c_str()); // Note the brackets
```